# Auto sizing cells to text in RTF with multiple rows

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, rtf

So I'm trying to build a string of RTF that contains 3 separate cells. One cell is a string of text, the next is just a straight line, the third is more text.

The goal is to have each cell fit to the text (on one line if possible) and the line fills in the gap between both the first and last cell.

The RTF that I was trying to create using \trautofit1, \clFitText, and \clNoWrap looks awful and just compresses everything into a single column. The table does not fit all the text in a single cell without wrapping.

Here is the bit of RTF I tried to create:

```
{\trowd\trautofit1\trgaph120\clFitText\clNoWrap\cellx1\cellx2\cellx9000
\intbl Text that should not wrap\cell
\intbl {\fs11\brdrb\brdrs\brdrwl0\par}\cell
\intbl\qr More text\cell
\row}
{\trowd\trautofit1\trgaph120\clFitText\clNoWrap\cellx1\cellx2\cellx9000
\intbl Row 2\cell
\intbl {\fs11\brdrb\brdrs\brdrwl0\par}\cell
\intbl\qr More text\cell
\row}
{\trowd\trautofit1\trgaph120\clFitText\clNoWrap\cellx1\cellx2\cellx9000
\intbl Text that should not wrap\cell
\intbl {\fs11\brdrb\brdrs\brdrwl0\par}\cell
\intbl\qr More text\cell
\row}
```

If you load the RTF below, this is what I'm expecting the output to look like:

```
{\trowd\trgaph120\cellx3500\cellx7900\cellx9000
\intbl\fs18 Row 1 (The cell should scale to this text)\cell
\intbl{\fs11\brdrb\brdrs\brdrwl0\par}\cell
\intbl\qr Time: 1:00\cell
\row}
{\trowd\trgaph120\cellx800\cellx7900\cellx9000
\intbl\fs18 Row 2\cell
\intbl{\fs11\brdrb\brdrs\brdrwl0\par}\cell
\intbl\qr Time: 1:00\cell
\row}
{\trowd\trgaph120\cellx2000\cellx7800\cellx9000
\intbl\fs18 Row 3 w/ extra words\cell
\intbl{\fs11\brdrb\brdrs\brdrwl0\par}\cell
\intbl\qr Time: 12:00\cell
\row}
```

Here are both versions on top of each other you can directly copy to an rtf file if that makes testing easier:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0
{\trowd\trgaph120\cellx3500\cellx7900\cellx9000
\intbl\fs18 Row 1 (The cell should scale to this text)\cell
\intbl{\fs11\brdrb\brdrs\brdrwl0\par}\cell
\intbl\qr Time: 1:00\cell
\row}
{\trowd\trgaph120\cellx800\cellx7900\cellx9000
\intbl\fs18 Row 2\cell
\intbl{\fs11\brdrb\brdrs\brdrwl0\par}\cell
\intbl\qr Time: 1:00\cell
\row}
{\trowd\trgaph120\cellx2000\cellx7800\cellx9000
\intbl\fs18 Row 3 w/ extra words\cell
\intbl{\fs11\brdrb\brdrs\brdrwl0\par}\cell
\intbl\qr Time: 12:00\cell
\row}
\pard\pard\par
{\trowd\trautofit1\trgaph120\clFitText\clNoWrap\cellx1\cellx2\cellx9000
\intbl Text that should not wrap\cell
\intbl {\fs11\brdrb\brdrs\brdrwl0\par}\cell
\intbl\qr More text\cell
\row}
{\trowd\trautofit1\trgaph120\clFitText\clNoWrap\cellx1\cellx2\cellx9000
\intbl Row 2\cell
\intbl {\fs11\brdrb\brdrs\brdrwl0\par}\cell
\intbl\qr More text\cell
\row}
{\trowd\trautofit1\trgaph120\clFitText\clNoWrap\cellx1\cellx2\cellx9000
\intbl Text that should not wrap\cell
\intbl {\fs11\brdrb\brdrs\brdrwl0\par}\cell
\intbl\qr More text\cell
\row}
}
```